# Old files are missing after git-svn clone with revision range control

Tags: svn, git

I'm trying to clone mplayer repository with git. Since there is too many revisions, I cloned with
  `git svn clone svn://svn.mplayerhq.hu/mplayer/trunk -r32000:HEAD mplayer-git`

After the cloning, there're 3 folders missing including ffmpeg, libdvdnav, libdvdread4, all of which are commited in very old revisions and has not been changed for a long time.
  I guess it's a strategy ignoring old files to save spaces, then I try

```
git svn clone svn://svn.mplayerhq.hu/mplayer/trunk -r1000:1250 mplayer-git2
```

The three folders still didn't show up. I really don't get it. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Are they real folders or svn:external links?

Comment: You are right! They are svn:externals links. So how to work it around in git?

Comment: You can fetch them as separate git repos and reconstruct the links with submodules. This way you get the correct remote modules at the current point in time, but you won't get the correct submodule-versions for past versions (but this information is only avilable in the svn repo if the externals them self contains revision numbers, very probably you won't miss anything).